# High number of redirects - impact on performance

Tags: redirect, iis, mod-rewrite

We're in the process of improving our website (IIS based, built in Sitecore 9.0) and one of the many topics we need to tackle are the redirects. We have a rewrite map with almost 6000 keys and the rewrite rules config has over 500 rules.

My questions are:

1. How much are these two variables affect the performance of the website?
2. Is there a way to mitigate this? (we already have the rules and map in config files)
3. Can I measure how much time is lost, assuming each request is processed through all the redirect rules and maps?

Any feedback would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to accurately measure the impact of the rewrite rules (testing with and without them). Then you can answer most of your own questions. If you created those rules for SEO, then they should be short lived and deleted on time. If they are meant to be permanent, then you have little to do.

Comment: so many rules can sometimes affect the site performance. you could try to use the IIS failed request tracing to check the rule is hitting by the requested URL or not. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)

Comment: Thanks both for the input

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to post the solution and mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.

If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.

We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal not really, first answer from Lex Li was the most helpful.